# Why is Schedule 80 conduit not available at home improvement stores?

Tags: conduit, pvc

Perhaps this is common knowledge, but I just found out that standard home improvement stores (HD, LO) do not carry Sch 80 conduit. I was always under impression that they would, and they even list it online, but it seems it is never available and cannot be ordered. That's also what staff at the store kinda confirmed, too (a funny thing was that the plumbing manager at LO thought that the electrical department would have a lot of stock...). They have some adapters and fittings that are SCH80, but no straight runs of conduit.

Does anyone know why that's the case? Seems like a pretty standard item to have. Just curious.

Comment: That *is* odd that they can't order it in for you...

Comment: They stock lines that sell in sufficient quantity. Go to a supplier that stocks it.

Comment: Yeah, it's a big metro area here (Las Vegas), tons of construction, but no supply...

Comment: Go to an electrical supply house. If you act like a newbie/homeowner they might not sell you breaker panels or certain other things out of liability concern. But conduit is just plastic (in this case) or metal pipe - if they ask, just tell them you're running the conduit and a licensed electrician will do the hookups and I'm sure they'll sell it to you.

Answer (score 3):

The big home improvement stores have elaborate systems in place to determine what sells in each store and figure out what products will bring the best return with the finite space they have for inventory.

There are lots of products that are very good or necessary that won't get a spot just because they are slow sellers.  Other retailers / wholesalers / distributors are set up to inventory more variety in specific categories.  So a local electrical supply will have things that are not as big of a seller.

Comment: Exactly.  Electrical supply houses sell systems of products.  Try installing something like Surface conduit, Home Depot won't stock left elbows because the computer says they're not as good a seller as right elbows.  The electrical supply stocks it all because they know you need it.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it's a local market thing but my local Home Depot has SCH 80 in stock now and I have purchased both sticks and fittings there in the past.  In fact they have it in stock now:

[image: Home Depot SCH 80 PVC Conduit]

Electrical supply houses will also have this, usually in stock as well.

Comment: interesting... I wonder if it is possible that there is less demand for it in the Southwest, because of the possible sun damage/sagging issues. Perhaps people buy way more EMT here, since there are few worries about corrosion and more PVC in the North...